# Build pdf from auxiliary files only

Tags: pdftex, auxiliary-files

After compiling with the option `draftmode` set, how can I create a PDF without recompiling everything.

I was looking all around, but somehow the main concern seems to be to get rid of the auxiliary files, instead of reusing them.

Comment: "compiling" in this context means making a pdf file from TeX sources, so it isn't clear what part of that you want to skip? The aux files have some information about cross references but none of the actual text so you can't make a pdf from "the auxiliary files only" ?

Comment: With compiling I ment running `pdflatex -draftmode my.tex`. I was under the impression, that the auxiliary files are used to store the typesetting, which I wanted to reuse somehow. But I guess the question is answered, if it's impossible.

Comment: You can look at the aux file in any text editor, typically they are only a few lines long, mainly it just has the numbers so that ... see section ?? on the first run can become see section 4 on teh second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aux files do not contain any information about typesetting. They are generated TeX source files, and their main use is to record numbers used on later runs, such as cross references from `\label` or the widths of `longtable` columns etc.